# Vbscript summary of numbers in all textfiles in a folder

Tags: variables, vbscript, integer, summary

Im trying to get the sum of numbers in existing x number of textfiles in a folder.
I have gotten so far that i can read 2 textfiles but they wont sum, the script *add* the numbers in the result
1,1+1,2 = 1,11,2 and not = 2,3 like i want it to, i understand there is something with integer and missmatch. But the only code i have found working is without textfiles as variables. as soon i need to read textilfes i get stuck. Please advice.

```
Option Explicit
Dim objFSO
Dim objFile1
Dim arrData1
Dim objFile2
Dim arrData2
Dim objFile3
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile1 = objFSO.OpenTextFile("..\testfolder\1.txt")
arrData1 = (objFile1.ReadLine)
objFile1.Close

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile2 = objFSO.OpenTextFile("..\testfolder\2.txt")
arrData2 = (objFile2.ReadLine)
objFile2.Close

Set objFile3 = objFSO.CreateTextFile("..\testfolder\sum.txt")
objFile3.WriteLine arrData1 + arrData2
objFile3.Close
```

Answer (score 0):

Reading from a file will give you strings; to use numerical strings in computings, you must convert them to numbers:

```
>> s1 = "47"
>> s2 = "11"
>> WScript.Echo s1 + s2
>> WScript.Echo CLng(s1) + CLng(s2)
>>
4711
58
```

(You should work on your strategy to work with more than one file.)

Comment: @micwar And you may want to validate that what you've read *can* be cast to a Long or else VBScript will throw you a nice little error message. Use the `IsNumeric()` function or a `RegExp`.